# Executing subprocess.Popen inside Python script in PyDev context is different than running in terminal

Tags: subprocess, pydev

I'm executing this code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/my/script.sh','--flag'] , stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(input='Y')
p.wait()
```

It works when executing it on the shell using "python scriptName.py",
BUT when executing using PyDev in Eclipse, it fails, the reason:

> /path/to/my/script.sh: line 111: service: command not found

This bash script "script.sh" contains the following command which causes the error:

> service mysqld restart

So "service" is not recognized when running the .sh script from the context of PyDev.
I guess it has to do with some ENV VAR configurations, couldn't find how to do it.

- BTW - Using "shell=True" when calling subprocess.Popen didn't solve it.

Comment: Which OS are you using (enviroment variable setting and where to set differs)

Answer (score 1):

`service` usually is located in `/usr/sbin`, and that this directory isn't on the `PATH`. As this usually contains administrative binaries and scripts which arn't designed to be run by everyone (only by admins/root), the `sbin` directories arn't always added to the `PATH` by default.

To check this, try to print `PATH` in your script (or add an `env` command).

To fix it, you could either

- set the PATH in your python script using `os.setenv`
- pass an `env` dict containing the correct `PATH` to `Popen`
- set the `PATH` in your shellscript
- use the full path in your shellscript
- set the `PATH` in eclipse